# Version Control for Binaries and the Computer Illiterate

Tags: version-control

I'm working on a project that deals with lots of people editing binaries, and as a coder, I'd seriously like some sort of version control. We don't deal with too much text, so I'm looking for something that allows file locking but doesn't care about merging, and which keeps track of changes. Also, many people working on the project are not coders, so someting with a gui would be nice. Does such a version control system exist?

Comment: What platform? What OS will the non-programmers be using?

Comment: @Oded Should that have a say in the feature set of the tool? Ideally any version control tool(commercial) would implement a feature in all platforms.

Comment: @Keerthi Ramalingam - Ideally. However, in the real world, some VCS tools are single platform or do not implement all the features for different platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subversion as the server will work well.

For windows users, [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) is a good interface - especially how it integrates with Explorer.

In regards to Merge issues on binary files - you may need to educate people on updates before commits, or possibly use exclusive lock on these files (yeah, kinda defeats the point, but with non technical people this may be the best solution).

Comment: Can you set up tortise SVN to do exclusive locking? Like I said, merging isn't an option here, so exclusive locking would work fairly well. All we really need is running backups and locking.

Comment: @nate - tortoiseSVN has a [`get lock`](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-locking.html) command, so yes, it can.

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest taking a look at [Perforce](http://www.perforce.com/). If you are into editing lots of images perforce also supports [diffing images](http://blog.perforce.com/blog/?p=1394) out of the box.

**File locking** can be done by educating users or you can make it default for all binary files. A user cannot checkout a file unless it is exclusively locked by him. This will ensure that the binary files need not be merged.

Subversion also suits this type of development scenario  but a user has to explicitly check whether the file is locked before editing it This is because subversion does not maintain an active connection with the server.
IMHO for perforce has nice GUI but subversion is FREE..

Answer (score 0):

I heard of [Alien Brain](http://www.nxn-software.com/), some times ago. It was described as some kind of version control system for graphists/designers.